# Системе не удается найти указанный путь

Tags: java, ajax, windows, spring-boot

Здравствуйте. Прохожу интересные туториалы и с одним примером непонятка. Консоль пишет

> \var\netgloo_blog\uploads (Системе не удается найти указанный путь)
>   \var\netgloo_blog\uploads\Test.txt (Системе не удается найти указанный путь)

Может кто проходил данное руководство? Не совсем понятно вообще как приложение работает. Должно ли оно создавать папку, указанную в application.properties или директория должна существовать?

Репозитория тут: 
https://github.com/netgloo/spring-boot-samples/tree/master/spring-boot-file-upload-with-ajax

Comment: какое руководство? какая у вас ОС?

Comment: руководство(туториал) netgloo_blog. Я дал ссылку на их гитхаб.

Comment: А второй вопрос?

Comment: У меня Windows 10

Comment: а у них Linux - вот и проблемы

Comment: Вопрос в том, как решить проблемы.

Comment: использовать другой путь разумеется

Comment: Я был бы оч благодарен за конкретную подсказку ибо в путях немного плаваю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в данном примере в файле `application.properties` определен путь, который является валидным для UNIX систем, но только не для Windows

```
# Directory where will be saved uploaded files. Make sure that the application 
# have write permissions on such directory.
netgloo.paths.uploadedFiles = /var/netgloo_blog/uploads
```

Вам необходимо указывать валидный путь для вашей системы, например, `C:\\Users\\myUser\\Documents`

Comment: Выбираю путь C:\Users. Консоль пишет C:Users\Test.txt (Системе не удается найти указанный путь)
Я так понимаю приложение должно скопировать файл в эту директорию(из Документы где он находится)

Comment: Я не знаю, почему у вас выдает такую ошибку. я только что поднял приложение и смог загрузить файл. File succesfully uploaded. скорее всего вы изменили проект как-то не так.

Comment: Скорее всего из-за кириллицы. C:\Users\Николай ... В файле свойств получается так: netgloo.paths.uploadedFiles = C:\Users\\u041D\u0438\u043A\u043E\u043B\u0430\u0439\\uploaded ... Консоль выдает это: C:Users\u041Dиколай\uploaded\FileIO.txt (Системе не удается найти указанный путь)

Comment: Наконец то получилось. Я изменил текущую директорию на C:\ и создал там папку upload. В фале свойств прописал путь C:\\uploaded. Спасибо.

Comment: это была проблема экранирования знака /. я обновил вопрос и добавил по две //